# I've been working on this table for days

Tags: php, html

I've been working on this for days and can't figure out what's wrong, it's for  class. It keeps returning 'syntax error unexpected end of file which i think means i missed a brace somewhere but i don't see where? Any help would be appreciated. I have two files and i'm trying to make a multiplication table in php.

Page 1:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Make a Multiplication Table!</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="./timestable.php" method="POST"/>
            <input type="number" value="1" name="a"/>
            <input type="number" value="1" name="b"/>
            <input type="submit"/>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>

<?php

$n = $_POST; // TODO what should $n really be? Replace the 10 with the user-supplied value from the form

// if we don't have a number, redirect back to the form page
if (isSet($n)) {
    header("Location: ./mult_form.php");
    exit;
}

?>
```

Page 2:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Your Table is Ready</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <?php 
            $a = $_POST['a'];
            $b = $_POST['b'];
            for ($i = 0; $i <($a)+1; $i++): 
            {
                $output.='<tr>';

                    for($j=1;$j<($b)+1;$j++)

                        {

                            $output.= '<td>'.($i*$j).'</td>';

                        }


            $output.='<tr>';

            }

        $output.='</table>';




            ?>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `for ($i = 0; $i <($a)+1; $i++):`  ->  `for ($i = 0; $i <($a)+1; $i++)`

Comment: <form action="./timestable.php" method="POST"/> remove the ./ amd the  / at the end

Comment: Improve your question title so that it describes the problem.

Comment: the second `$output.='<tr>';` should be `$output.='</tr>';`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apart from like 10 things you could/should change let's cut to the chase.
You never output the `$output` variable. Use:

```
echo $output;
```

right after the `$output.='</table>';` and you should be fine.

---

**EDIT:** corrected code as explained in comments.

That's the fully corrected page 1:

```
<?php

if (!isset($_POST['n'])) {
    header("Location: mult_form.php");
    exit;
}

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Make a Multiplication Table!</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="timestable.php" method="POST"/>
            <input type="number" value="1" name="a"/>
            <input type="number" value="1" name="b"/>
            <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $_POST['n'];?>" name="n"/>
            <input type="submit"/>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Note that if you want to set a header field with `header()` you need to have a clear output buffer. This means not a single character has been output yet. Otherwise, the HTTP header will be automatically closed and the HTTP body will begin. This means that the `header()` comes to late and is actually ignored.
So, no redirect if the PHP is after any HTML character. That's why I put it at the start of the code.

You will need to implement `mult_form.php` which posts the `n` field.

The second page is this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Your Table is Ready</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <?php 
            $a = intval($_POST['a']);
            $b = intval($_POST['b']);
            $n = intval($_POST['n']);
            $output = '';
            for ($i = 1; $i <= $a; $i++)
            {
                $output .= '<tr>';
                for ($j = 1; $j <= $b; $j++)
                {
                    $output .= "<td>{$i * $j * $n}</td>";
                }
                $output .= '</tr>';
            }
            echo $output;
            ?>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Note that the `$output` is initialized as an empty string so that the first `.=` concatenation actually concatenates string to string and not an undefined value to string, which might mess up the whole concatenation drama that is going on here :)

This should do it.

If this doesn't work be more specific, maybe post another question with your fresh code. This question should be considered fully answered now.

Have a nice day!

Comment: yeah? that still doesn't work? are there other errors I'm not seeing?

Comment: Let's see. There's a spurious `:` after the first `for()` statement. You may also want to use `intval($_POST['a'])` just to be on the safe side of reading in the post variables. The first `for()` starts from 0, not 1. Which should be wrong, because multiplication tables start from 1. The second `<tr>` should be a closing tag (`</tr>`). It also looks like you want a multiplier `$n`. Then you should test in the first page for `!isset($n)` (all lower case and leading not `!`). Also remove the leading `./` in the redirects. If you need the `$n` in `timestable.php` you must pass it along.

Comment: To pass it along add this to the form: `<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $n; ?>" name="n" />`. Next, read it in `timestable.php`: `$n = intval($_POST['n']);`. Finally, multiply it into all cells with `$i*$j*$n`. That's not all but a good step ahead. You obviously need the first page where you input `$n`. Don't know why you wouldn't put it in the form already, but that's your choice.

Comment: I've just updated my answer with code. There were some bugs but right now it's bugless as far as I can tell. See if this works and post a new question if necessary.